# Why does array template iterator declaration requires specifying array size?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

```
array<int,4> a1 = {1,2,3,4};

array<int,4>::iterator itr1 = a1.begin(); //Ok

array<int>::iterator itr2 = a1.begin(); //Compiler error. why not allowed?

//Iteration
    while(itr1 != a1.end())
    {
        cout<<"\n "<<*itr1;
        itr1++;
    }
```

since we always iterate from begin() to end() Is there any special reason for mentioning size in array iterator template?

Comment: Downvoters please comment.

Comment: What do you expect `array<int>` to be `std::array` takes two template params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a template with different template arguments the generated classes are not in any sense the same. So `std::array<int, 1>` and `std::array<int, 2` are not the same type. When you instantiate the template a specialised copy of the class is created thus the above example   creates two distinct specialisations of `std::array` one with the arguments `<int, 1>` and one with `<int, 2>`. Even though the specialisations have very similar implementation they are not the same. As a consequence of this `std::array<int, 1>::iterator` is not the same type as `std::array<int, 2>::iterator`. They are two different specialisations.

Your attempt with `std::array<int>`, which seems pretty logical at first glance, is not correct because `std::array` expects two template arguments and not one. The `auto` keyword was introduced in part to make these kinds of things easier, use it.

**PS:** Thanks to `aaronman` for clarifying the answer.

Comment: WTF, how does this even answer the question, your answer has nothing to do with iterators

Comment: I expanded on that. I probably got a little carried away with the answer, sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry this answer is still not right it shouldn't be accepted

Comment: @aaronman. In what way do you think it's wrong? I'd be glad to change it if you have a better or more clear wording than me.

Comment: `array<int>` is not a type, make the distinction that any templates passed different params are different types including `array<int,1>` and `array<int,2>`. Iterator types are nested typedefs and thus dependent on the template params. `std::vector` only needs 1 template param for it's iter because it only needs 1 template param for it's iter. and for extra credit tell him to use auto so he doesn't have to ask this question again

Comment: Absolutely I will rewrite the answer to reflect that for the sake of future readers.

Comment: I think the distinction that array<int,1> and array<int,2> are different types and any different template params passed make a template a different type is very important

Comment: Absolutely I totally agree.

Comment: @aaronman: For completeness, while access to the container's `iterator` type is through nested qualifiers, the `iterator` type itself is implementation defined.  Hence, an implementation is permitted to make `iterator` a non-dependent name (using no template arguments from the enclosing class) or have `std::vector<int>::iterator` be the same type as any `std::array<int, N>::iterator` variant, as long as the resulting `iterator` type be at least of the forward iterator category.

Comment: @TannerSansbury yes but even so you need to get the type with `std::array<int, N>::iterator` so even if it's not dependent you need to make sure you have the right one

Comment: @aaronman: Concur, no argument there.  I just wanted to clarify that `iterator` type is implementation defined, as this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938783/19938833?noredirect=1#comment29673589_19938833) seemed to suggest otherwise, and the edited answer makes claims about the implementation.  It is subtle detail, but I wanted accentuate the difference, as I have seen it be the source of a problem in code.

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` is **a compile time fixed size** container which has its advantages. (For a run time dynamic container you can use `std::vector`) The size must be set at compile time so, `array<int>` is illegal and even doesn't exists as a type.

This type is a good alternative for traditional arrays such as `int a[123]`. You can pass `std::array` to functions easier than traditional arrays and whenever you're using `std::array` you know the length.

Functions `.begin()` and `.end()` make it consistence to other containers and you can iterate over it like other STL types. It's important to know `array<int, 10>` and `array<int, 11>` are two different types with same interfaces.

Comment: This question is a disaster, I expect this when answering java questions but c++11, for shame!

Comment: @aaronman: Hahaaa, Poor java programmers,  I hope they don't see your comment :-))